# An error occurred while installing tzinfo (0.3.33), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tzinfo

Hello i am running bundle install and receiving the following error message. I am using the rails installer kit @ http://railsinstaller.org/

Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.
1/cache/tzinfo-0.3.33.gem
An error occurred while installing tzinfo (0.3.33), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install tzinfo -v '0.3.33'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows and use PIK for ruby version control.   I ran

```
pik gem install tzinfo
```

that installed gem on all versions of ruby.

then ran bundle install... Had a few other similar errors that I resolved in the same manner.

Bottom line: install gem per the error description.

if you don't use PIK or RVM just run: gem install tzinfo

good luck